# How to create a set of record from a set of text?

Tags: json, postgresql, recordset

I have this code `json_object_keys('{"A": 1, "B": 0, "C": 5}'::json)` which returns a set of text like this:

```
json_object_keys
----------------
| A |
-----
| B |
-----
| C |
-----
```

Based on this `json_object_keys` result, I want to create a temporary recordset or table to loop through these to perform update to a table column where its equal to each key.
So how do I create a recordset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do not need to explicitly create a temporary table, because you can use the [`IN (subquery)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) expression, example:

```
update my_table
set some_column = some_value
where key_column in (
    select json_object_keys('{"A": 1, "B": 0, "C": 5}'::json));
```

In fact, the server creates a temporary recordset in memory from the subquery during the execution of the query.

However, if you do need a named temporary table, use [`CREATE TABLE AS`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

```
create temporary table my_temp_table as
select json_object_keys('{"A": 1, "B": 0, "C": 5}'::json);
```